# How to add content of file after text in div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, file-io, optionmenu

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Culminating</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJnj2nWoM86eU8Bq2G4lSNz3udIkZT4YY&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
        <!-- Calling the Google Maps API -->
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="googleMap"></div>
        <div id="right_pane_results">hi</div>
        <div id="bottom_pane_options">
            <div id="parameters">
                <h4>Please choose a parameter:</h4>
                <script>
                    $.get('./test.txt', function(data) {
                        $("#parameters").append(data);
                    }, 'text');
                </script>
                <?php //include("test.html") ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

style.css

```
.content {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 15px;
}

#parameters  {
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    margin: 0px;
}

#bottom_pane_options {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 20%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

---

text file `test.txt`:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Parameter 1</option>
    <option value="2">Parameter 2</option>
    <option value="3">Parameter 3</option>
</select>
```

---

I would like the output to look like:

**Please choose a parameter: `option menu from test.txt here`**

Right now, the option menu is appearing under the text.  I have tried `display: inline;` but that broke it.  I'm sure this is a quick fix but I am new to `jQuery` and `CSS`.

Comment: i had updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try floating the h4 element to the left. That will break the container though so use the code at link below to clearifx the container. Forgot to mention that, you have to give the h4 element a specific width because it is  a block level emelement and will take up as much width as it need( Even if it means taking up the whole line). Inline-block should have worked on it but the width might be an issue.

http://www.lswebapps.com/code-snippet/css-clearfix/

Comment: Now that everything is in line it looks weird.  The `<h4>` tag seems to be giving the text a padding or margin on the top and bottom even though I have given both `0px` in CSS.  I have also made  `line-height` `0px` but there is still some space.  Any idea why?

Comment: Try using negative margin although I donot seem to comprehend why your method did not work. Oh the joys of css.